# I'm trying to send string by a bundle and access it in another fragment by container activity's method but it's not returning the string

Tags: android, fragment

I'm trying to send data from one fragment to another by help of the container activity's methods but it's not returning anything on the fragment(where the value is needed) so the string I want to toast is not toasted

My Code:

container activity methods:
    Bundle bundle;

```
public void saveData(int id,final Bundle data) {
this.bundle=data;
}
public Bundle getSavedData() {

    return this.bundle;
}
```

fragment from which bundle is being set onclick:

```
     public void onClick(View view) {
    Main_Page main_page=new Main_Page();
    user_email=autoCompletetTextView.getText().toString().trim();
     int key=1;
    switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.proceed:
           //profile_pic si=new profile_pic();
           Bundle args=new Bundle();
           args.putString("email",user_email);
           main_page.saveData(key,args);}}
```

fragment where data is received:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
Main_Page main=new Main_Page();
Bundle bundle = main.getSavedData();
            if (bundle != null) {
         String myString = bundle.getString("email").toString().trim();
       Toast.makeText(getContext(),myString,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: Probably `bundle` is not `static` so when try to get using new instance will give `null`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK thanks a lot sir you have just saved my life

Answer (score 0):

Both `Main_Page` objects are different here. So you can not get Bundle of old Main_Page object while creating another `Main_Page` object.

They both are the different object of same class.

Answer (score 0):

send fragment inside use this code

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "value");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
ReciveClass receiveobj = new Receiveclass();
receiveobj .setArguments(bundle);
```

receive or get class inside use this code

```
  String getValue = getArguments().getString("key");
```

this above code as use get information easily.

Comment: @Srinivas Nahak Are u try this one

Comment: Sir I have tried it before but it has given NullPointer error as the fragment is not attatched to the activity but after adding static to bundle it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

After adding static to the bundle declaration it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I hope the container is an Activity. Fragment one is saving data and Fragment two is retrieving the data. If the activity is recreated before retrieving the data then the bundle would be null. Make the bundle **static** and try it is working.

Or you can use Singleton class to pass data.

```
public class EmailDataHolder {

private static EmailDataHolder mInstance;
private String mEmail = "";

public static EmailDataHolder getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new EmailDataHolder();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    mEmail = email;
}

public void getEmail() {
    return this.mEamil;
}
```

}

Set data from fragment one -----

```
EmailDataHolder.getnInstance().setEmail(email);
```

Retrieve email from fragment two ---

```
EmailDataHolder.getInstance().getEmail();
```